# flask login creación de grupo dentro e usuario logeado

Tags: python, flask

me encuentro creando una web con flask, python, postgres en la cual he llegado a un punto donde quiero que un usuario ya registrado y logeado pueda crear un grupo de amigos y colocarse el o otro como administrador de ese grupo en especifico. he tratado de realizar esta accion con flask-login asi como lo realice con el usuario de creación inicial mas no me funciona alguna idea o alguna ruta que seguir?

```
@auth_bp.route("/Team_create/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def Team_create_form():
    
    form = CrearEquipo()
    Userl = User.query.all()
    

    if form.validate_on_submit():
         Teamname = form.Liga.data

teamm.save()

        login_user(teamm, remember=True)
        next_page = request.args.get('next', None)
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('public.index')
        return redirect(next_page)
```

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(Equipo_id):
       
    return User.get_by_id(int(Equipo_id))
```

```
class Equipos(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Equipos'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
def __init__(self,....)
 self.Teamname = Teamname

def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Generalinf {self.Teamname}>' 
    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

```
Could not build url for endpoint 'auth.pequipo'. Did you forget to specify values ['Teamname']?
```

```
@auth_bp.route("/Mi_Equipo/<Teamname>")
def pequipo(Teamname):

    invocadores = Equipo.query.filter_by(Teamname=Teamname).first_or_404()
    logo = Image(invocadores.Teamlogo)
return render_template("auth/interfaces_jugador/Ei_equipo.html")
```

Comment: Por favor sube el código con lo que has intentaado y la traza de error, para que podamos ver que sucede las personas que intentamos ayudarte.

Comment: ya agregue el código este es  y para la creación de usuario estoy usando el mismo y funciona lo único que cambia son los nombres